# Bootstrap como imprimir cores de fundo da tabela?

Tags: bootstrap-3

Boa Tarde

Gostaria de imprimir com bootstrap as cores que eu coloquei na minha tabela
exemplo:

```
<td bgcolor="#000">
```

Mas quando vou imprimir muda para fundo branco e letras pretas.

Eu andei lendo que para imprimir a tabela colorida está relacionado com o arquivo **bootstrap.min.css**, eu encontrei a linha onde estão todas as informações relacionadas ao **@media print**

Já adicionei

```
td{background-color: #0000 !important;}
```

Também não funcionou.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Sei que a pergunta é meio antiga, mas vou te dar uma solução e de qualquer forma fica ai como registro.*

**Por default as impressoras *não imprimem nada que esteja no CSS como background*, seja imagem ou color**

Para que seja impresso os estilos de `background` o usuário precisa por conta própria escolher **"graficos de segundo plano"** nas configurações da impressora como na imagem abaixo

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Como já discutido nessas duas perguntas a impressora por *Default* não imprimi nada que for `background` no CSS, nem imagens, nem cores, nem nada.

[Imprimir página com Background](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/269790/imprimir-p%C3%A1gina-com-background/269803#269803)

[Aplicar marca d'água sem afetar o texto](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/274605/aplicar-marca-d%C3%A1gua-sem-afetar-o-texto/274612#274612)

Porém existem técnicas que podem resolver esse problema. Como vou mostrar abaixo.

**O primeiro passo é criar o seu CSS exclusivo que só vai usando o `@print`**

Veja o exemplo abaixo funcionando, a cor vai ficar vermelha na impressão. A técnica é aplicar um `box-shadow` para dentro da célula, assim vc pode colocar a cor que quiser e vai aparecer na impressão sem problemas.

**Pode testar por aqui mesmo dando o <kbd>Ctrl+P</kbd> que vai funcionar!**

```css
html, body {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

table thead tr th {
    background: greenyellow; /* cor antes da impressão */
}

@media print{
  table thead tr th{
    box-shadow: 0 0 0 1000px red inset;  /* cor para impressão */
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
    <table border="1">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Item 1</th>
                <th>Item 2</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td>Texto 1</td>
                <td>Texto2</td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>
```

Resultado da impressão com o código acima, repare no box vermelho!

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Se vc quiser simular como a sua impressão vai ficar direto nã página sem precisar ficar apertando <kbd>Ctrl+P</kbd> toda hora basta habilitar o "Print Preview" direto pelo Dev Tools do Chrome dessa forma, aperte <kbd>F12</kbd>:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 0):

Na chamada do seu css, veja se vc declarou o "media"

Exemplo:

```
<link href='css/bootstrap.min.css' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' media='all'>
```

Comment: Oi coloquei não mudou nada, nossa tanto trabalho só para imprimir uma merda de cor, chega ser ridículo isso.

Comment: no seu bootstrap.min.css na parte do @media, adicione tb -webkit-print-color-adjust: exact;

Comment: td{background-color: #000 !important;-webkit-print-color-adjust: exact;}. Está assim no meu código

Comment: mesmo assim não foi

Answer (score -1):

O bootstrap tem realmente um problema com impressão, ele não te dá tanta liberdade. Primeiramente porque ele já usa o `!important` nas suas propriedades.
Então se você adicionar: `td{background-color: #000 !important;}` não irá adiantar, mas isso por conta de uma regra do CSS.
tags/classes encadeadas tem prioridade e há um no arquivo no boostrap para o `td`:

```
.table td,
.table th {
  background-color: #fff !important;
}
```

E isso não permite que você troque utilizando apenas o `td`, mas você pode substituí-la:

```
.table td,
.table th {
  background-color: #000 !important; /* Só mudar a cor */
}
```

Na versão [não minificada](https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.css) você encontra essa regra na linha 256;

Ou melhor, não recomendo substituí-la diretamente no bootstrap, mas num arquivo abaixo dele, mas que contenha exatamente: `.table td`;

Answer (score -1):

se você quer adicionar na linha do código você deve fazer:

```html
<table class="table">
  <tr>
    <td style="background-color: red;">Link</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Caso deseje o bootstrap tem opções padronizadas que já te traz um background que você pode querer usar:

```html
<table class="table">
  <tr>
    <td class="active">CORES</td>
    <td class="success">CORES</td>
    <td class="warning">CORES</td>
    <td class="danger">CORES</td>
    <td class="info">CORES</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Ou então você pode adicionar uma classe e chamar a cor que desejar para ela em um arquivo css separado que é o mais correto.

```css
.minha-cor {
 background-color: blue;
 color: white;
}
```

```html
<table class="table">
  <tr>
    <td class="minha-cor">AZUL</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```