# CSS: como inserir um elemento imagem centralizado no papel?

Tags: css, css3

Pessoal como posso inserir um elemento imagem centralizado como logo em um documento html, para definir formato "@media print"?

No modelo estou aplicando em screen, para visualização em tela.

```html
<html>
<head>
<title></title>
<style>
@media print {}
@media screen {
  header::before{
    content:url(https://image.freepik.com/vetores-gratis/tux-personagem-com-papel-em-branco-para-o-seu-texto_52478.jpg);
    content: "";
    background-image:url(https://image.freepik.com/vetores-gratis/tux-personagem-com-papel-em-branco-para-o-seu-texto_52478.jpg);
    background-size: 100% 100%;
    display: inline-block;
    /*size of your image*/
    height: 100px;
    width:100px;
  }
  header{
    /* Largura total - Se você omitir ocupará toda a linha */
    padding-top: 20em;
    width:100%; 
    height: auto;
    /*background: #fff url("https://image.freepik.com/vetores-gratis/tux-personagem-com-papel-em-branco-para-o-seu-texto_52478.jpg") 15em -5em no-repeat;
    background-size: 120px Auto;*/
    /*background: none;*/
    padding-top: 0em;
    display: block;
    margin:0;
  }
  h1,h2, h3{text-align:center; margin:0;}
  p{text-align:justify; text-indent:3em;}
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<header>
<h1>Titulo Principal</h1>
<h2>Titulo 2</h2>
<h3>titulo 3</h3>
</header>
</p><p>Nulla a sem arcu. Ut eleifend lectus in suscipit vulputate. Nulla diam nibh, malesuada sit amet interdum sit amet, dictum vitae diam. Proin a malesuada purus, nec congue orci. Duis posuere egestas mauris, id egestas nibh sollicitudin quis. Morbi nec ex eu dui iaculis dictum eu sed dui. Quisque vel sollicitudin risus. Morbi eget elementum neque, vitae vestibulum nisi. Mauris at purus est. Nunc tempor eleifend faucibus. Fusce eget libero congue, porta turpis et, sodales augue. Suspendisse tincidunt nunc ac convallis iaculis. Nam sit amet ex ac nunc laoreet tincidunt. Aliquam tempus auctor scelerisque. Nam pulvinar nibh at euismod aliquam. Aenean libero dolor, lacinia iaculis sodales eu, blandit eget risus.

</p><p>Praesent eget dolor ut arcu commodo scelerisque. Nullam luctus, tortor sed pellentesque commodo, odio dolor rhoncus lorem, et vestibulum urna ipsum id erat. Pellentesque velit nibh, viverra quis varius sed, rutrum et tellus. Morbi tempor pharetra efficitur. Sed id tincidunt arcu, nec lacinia arcu. Nam congue libero ac pellentesque pharetra. In vel aliquet lorem. Nam vitae dolor accumsan, auctor sem eget, dapibus elit.

</p><p>Ut tempor elementum lorem, eu condimentum odio. Nullam molestie tellus sit amet quam euismod rutrum. Nulla in felis commodo, tristique nunc eu, tristique nisl. Orci varius natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Aliquam id efficitur lorem. In faucibus nunc in eros tincidunt, id cursus sem cursus. Nulla vehicula, nibh non egestas vehicula, enim ipsum mollis neque, sed eleifend nulla purus id mi. Proin at vestibulum nibh. Duis dapibus eget diam vulputate eleifend. Vestibulum ac diam eget arcu tempor commodo. Phasellus sed ipsum eget enim aliquam lobortis. In vulputate faucibus massa eget tristique. Aliquam sit amet dolor felis.

</p><p>Nulla non urna nec tellus faucibus lobortis eget id lectus. Ut porttitor tellus eget sodales molestie. Quisque malesuada diam in viverra efficitur. Proin condimentum suscipit libero. Nulla lobortis erat risus, eget facilisis odio consequat sit amet. Pellentesque lobortis feugiat commodo. Proin aliquet, metus commodo viverra elementum, nunc ante convallis diam, a euismod magna felis quis nisi. Fusce quis lectus in lacus dignissim maximus nec vulputate felis. Praesent mauris justo, dignissim sed leo porta, vestibulum egestas elit. Mauris egestas pretium lorem, at placerat nibh scelerisque ut.

</p><p>Quisque dignissim justo vel iaculis eleifend. Vestibulum ultrices condimentum imperdiet. Aenean elit nisi, volutpat sed sodales eget, fermentum non lorem. Fusce vel pellentesque ex. Proin at velit sed turpis vulputate ultrices. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nullam aliquet scelerisque enim, vitae malesuada magna. Quisque porttitor, lorem elementum accumsan ornare, risus urna mattis ipsum, eu semper sapien libero vitae mi. Aliquam sit amet molestie enim, vitae tempor neque. Praesent eget odio quam. 
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: O único problema é que por padrão nenhum background é impresso na hora que vc manda imprimir. A impressora por default ignora todas as imagens e cores de background... Basta vc entrar em qualquer página e fazer um teste apertando Ctrl+P e ver se o Background aparece, por default não costuma aparecer, a não ser que o usuário tenha feita a configuração para tal.

Comment: Possível duplicata de [Imprimir página com Background](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/269790/imprimir-p%c3%a1gina-com-background)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Como você está trabalhando com `background`, então você **precisa** definir a largura do `header:before` como `100%`. Para a imagem não ficar enorme, basta utilizar o `background-size` com `px` ao invés de `%`.

Para posicionar pasta utilizar `background-position` e `background-repeat` para evitar que a imagem se repita dentro do conteúdo.

```html
<html>
<head>
<title></title>
<style>
@media screen {
  header::before{
    content:url(https://image.freepik.com/vetores-gratis/tux-personagem-com-papel-em-branco-para-o-seu-texto_52478.jpg);
    content: "";
    background-image:url(https://image.freepik.com/vetores-gratis/tux-personagem-com-papel-em-branco-para-o-seu-texto_52478.jpg);
    
    background-size: 100px 100px;
    background-position:center;
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
    -webkit-print-color-adjust: exact;
    color-adjust: exact;
    
    display: inline-block;
    /*size of your image*/
    height: 100px;
    width:100%;
  }
  header{
    /* Largura total - Se você omitir ocupará toda a linha */
    padding-top: 20em;
    width:100%; 
    height: auto;
    /*background: #fff url("https://image.freepik.com/vetores-gratis/tux-personagem-com-papel-em-branco-para-o-seu-texto_52478.jpg") 15em -5em no-repeat;
    background-size: 120px Auto;*/
    /*background: none;*/
    padding-top: 0em;
    display: block;
    margin:0;
  }
  h1,h2, h3{text-align:center; margin:0;}
  p{text-align:justify; text-indent:3em;}
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<header>
<h1>Titulo Principal</h1>
<h2>Titulo 2</h2>
<h3>titulo 3</h3>
</header>
</p><p>Nulla a sem arcu. Ut eleifend lectus in suscipit vulputate. Nulla diam nibh, malesuada sit amet interdum sit amet, dictum vitae diam. Proin a malesuada purus, nec congue orci. Duis posuere egestas mauris, id egestas nibh sollicitudin quis. Morbi nec ex eu dui iaculis dictum eu sed dui. Quisque vel sollicitudin risus. Morbi eget elementum neque, vitae vestibulum nisi. Mauris at purus est. Nunc tempor eleifend faucibus. Fusce eget libero congue, porta turpis et, sodales augue. Suspendisse tincidunt nunc ac convallis iaculis. Nam sit amet ex ac nunc laoreet tincidunt. Aliquam tempus auctor scelerisque. Nam pulvinar nibh at euismod aliquam. Aenean libero dolor, lacinia iaculis sodales eu, blandit eget risus.

</p><p>Praesent eget dolor ut arcu commodo scelerisque. Nullam luctus, tortor sed pellentesque commodo, odio dolor rhoncus lorem, et vestibulum urna ipsum id erat. Pellentesque velit nibh, viverra quis varius sed, rutrum et tellus. Morbi tempor pharetra efficitur. Sed id tincidunt arcu, nec lacinia arcu. Nam congue libero ac pellentesque pharetra. In vel aliquet lorem. Nam vitae dolor accumsan, auctor sem eget, dapibus elit.

</p><p>Ut tempor elementum lorem, eu condimentum odio. Nullam molestie tellus sit amet quam euismod rutrum. Nulla in felis commodo, tristique nunc eu, tristique nisl. Orci varius natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Aliquam id efficitur lorem. In faucibus nunc in eros tincidunt, id cursus sem cursus. Nulla vehicula, nibh non egestas vehicula, enim ipsum mollis neque, sed eleifend nulla purus id mi. Proin at vestibulum nibh. Duis dapibus eget diam vulputate eleifend. Vestibulum ac diam eget arcu tempor commodo. Phasellus sed ipsum eget enim aliquam lobortis. In vulputate faucibus massa eget tristique. Aliquam sit amet dolor felis.

</p><p>Nulla non urna nec tellus faucibus lobortis eget id lectus. Ut porttitor tellus eget sodales molestie. Quisque malesuada diam in viverra efficitur. Proin condimentum suscipit libero. Nulla lobortis erat risus, eget facilisis odio consequat sit amet. Pellentesque lobortis feugiat commodo. Proin aliquet, metus commodo viverra elementum, nunc ante convallis diam, a euismod magna felis quis nisi. Fusce quis lectus in lacus dignissim maximus nec vulputate felis. Praesent mauris justo, dignissim sed leo porta, vestibulum egestas elit. Mauris egestas pretium lorem, at placerat nibh scelerisque ut.

</p><p>Quisque dignissim justo vel iaculis eleifend. Vestibulum ultrices condimentum imperdiet. Aenean elit nisi, volutpat sed sodales eget, fermentum non lorem. Fusce vel pellentesque ex. Proin at velit sed turpis vulputate ultrices. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nullam aliquet scelerisque enim, vitae malesuada magna. Quisque porttitor, lorem elementum accumsan ornare, risus urna mattis ipsum, eu semper sapien libero vitae mi. Aliquam sit amet molestie enim, vitae tempor neque. Praesent eget odio quam. 
</body>
</html>
```

Para forçar o navegador imprimir a imagem, use [color-adjust](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/-webkit-print-color-adjust)

Comment: O único problema é que por padrão nenhum background é impresso na hora que vc manda imprimir. A impressora por default ignora todas as imagens e cores de background...

Comment: @hugocsl é verdade. Alterei o código para forçar o navegador imprimir a imagem.

Comment: @britodfbr Não se esqueça de substituir `@media screen` por `@media print` quando for testar. Deixei como `screen` para mostrar o resultado na tela.

Comment: @ValdeirPsr ok.

Comment: perfeito! muito obrigado. Mas tenho uma duvida. Porque é utilizado o background-size e o (widht + height) no mesmo objeto?

Comment: O `height` e `width` servem para atribuir a largura e altura do conteúdo onde será exibido a imagem. Quando definimos a largura maior que o tamanho da imagem, nós podemos ajustar/posicionar onde a imagem será inserida dentro desse "elemento". O `background-size` vai apenas definir a altura e a largura da imagem, apenas.

Answer (score 0):

Use z-index no header. Ou apenas insira uma tag `<img>` em vez de `background-image` no elemento. Eu particularmente acho que fazer com uma tag `<img>` seria infinitamente mais fácil.

```html
<html>
<head>
<title></title>
<style>
@media screen {
    header::before
    {
        content: "";
        background-image: url(https://image.freepik.com/vetores-gratis/tux-personagem-com-papel-em-branco-para-o-seu-texto_52478.jpg);
        background-size: 100% 100%;
        width: 100px;
        height: 100px;
        display: inline-block;
    }
    header {
        width: 100%;
        height: auto;
        padding-top: 0em;
        display: block;
        margin: 0;
    }
    h1, h2, h3 {
        text-align: center;
        margin:0;
    }
    p {
        text-align: justify;
        text-indent: 3em;}
    }
}
@media print {
    header::before, header
    {
        z-index: 1;
    }
    header::before {
        content: url(https://image.freepik.com/vetores-gratis/tux-personagem-com-papel-em-branco-para-o-seu-texto_52478.jpg);
        width: 100px;
        height: 100px;
        display: block;
    }
    header {
        width: 100%;
        height: auto;
        padding-top: 0em;
        display: block;
        margin: 0;
    }
    h1, h2, h3 {
        text-align: center;
        margin:0;
    }
    p {
        text-align: justify;
        text-indent: 3em;
    }
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<header>
<h1>Titulo Principal</h1>
<h2>Titulo 2</h2>
<h3>titulo 3</h3>
</header>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: infelizmente o documento html não poderá ser alterado. Então tags inseridas estará fora de cogitação. :(

Comment: Tem algum motivo "tecnológico" bom pra isso ou é regra do negócio?

Comment: regra de negócio.

Comment: Ah, entendo o problema.