# Gráfico não se adequa a impressão

Tags: javascript, html, css, impressora, gráfico

Tenho uma página que apresenta vários gráficos e um botão pra impressão.

Embora eu tenha colocado os gráficos em um tamanho pequeno e um do lado do outro pra dar pra imprimir vários gráficos na mesma folha, quando eu mando imprimir, imprime um embaixo do outro.

**Como está a minha página:**

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

**Como sai na impressão:**

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

A página:

```
<div id="nota-print">      
        <!-- Main -->
        <div class="content-lg container">
          <div class="row margin-b-20">
              <div class="col-sm-6">
                  <h2>Prev x Real Month</h2>
              </div>
          </div>
          <div class="row">
            <div class="col-sm-12 sm-margin-b-50">
              <?php 

                include("conn.php");
                require_once("graf-gptw-1.php");
              ?>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
</div>
        <a id="nota" class="btn btn-info btn-lg" onclick="printPageArea('nota-print');" title="Imprimir">
            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-print"></span> Imprimir 
        </a>
```

Esse é o js que faz o print:

```
function printPageArea(nota)
{

    var nav = window.navigator.userAgent;
    var msie = nav.indexOf("MSIE ");

    if (msie > 0 || !!navigator.userAgent.match(/Trident.*rv\:11\./))  // If Internet Explorer, return version number
    {
                    var PrintWebBrowser = '<OBJECT ID="iPrint" WIDTH=0 HEIGHT=0 CLASSID="CLSID:8856F961-340A-11D0-A96B-00C04FD705A2"></OBJECT>';
                    var oldContent = document.body.innerHTML;
                               document.body.innerHTML = document.getElementById(nota).innerHTML;
                               document.body.insertAdjacentHTML('beforeEnd', PrintWebBrowser );
                               iPrint.ExecWB(7,2);
                               iPrint.outerHTML = "";
                               document.body.innerHTML = oldContent;
                               //var element = $('button[name="search"]');
               //executa o evento "click" no elemento 
               //element.trigger('click');
    }
    else  // para outros navegadores
    {
                    var win = window.open('', 'Nota de fechamento', 'location=no,width=1200,height=800');
                    var printContent = document.getElementById(nota);

                    var style = '@page { size: landscape !important;  margin: 1cm; }';
                    var html = '<html><head><title></title><style media="print">' + style + '</style> </head><body><div class="nota">' + printContent.innerHTML + '</div></body></html>';

                    win.document.write(html);
                    win.document.close();
                    win.focus();
                    win.print();

                    win.close(); 

    }
}
```

Alguém sabe como fazer pra imprimir como está na página? Tem algum css que eu possa colocar e tal?

EDIT:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="pt-br" class="no-js">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8"/>
        <title>Sistema Obeya - Qualité</title>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
        <meta content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" name="viewport"/>
        <meta content="" name="description"/>
        <meta content="" name="author"/>

        <!-- GLOBAL MANDATORY STYLES -->
        <link href="http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Hind:300,400,500,600,700" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
        <link href="vendor/simple-line-icons/simple-line-icons.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
        <link href="vendor/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>

        <!-- PAGE LEVEL PLUGIN STYLES -->
        <link href="css/animate.css" rel="stylesheet">
        <link href="vendor/swiper/css/swiper.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>

        <!-- THEME STYLES -->
        <link href="css/layout.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>


        <!-- Favicon -->
        <link rel="shortcut icon" href="favicon.ico"/>
        <script src="vendor/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

        <script src="code/highcharts.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

        <!-- Impressão -->
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script src="print.js"></script>

    </head>

    <body>

    <!--É do highcharts -->
    <script src="code/modules/exporting.js"></script>


            <!-- Menu -->
        <header class="header navbar-fixed-top">
            <nav class="navbar" role="navigation">
                <div class="container">
                    <div class="menu-container">
                        <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".nav-collapse">
                            <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                            <span class="toggle-icon"></span>
                        </button>
                        <!-- Logo -->
                        <div class="logo">
                            <a class="logo-wrap" href="principal.php">
                                <h2 class="logo-img logo-img-main" alt="Asentus Logo" style="color:#fff">OBEYA </h2>
                                <h2 class="logo-img logo-img-active" alt="Asentus Logo">OBEYA </h2>
                            </a>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse nav-collapse">
                        <div class="menu-container">
                            <ul class="navbar-nav navbar-nav-right">
                                <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-item-child nav-item-hover" href="principal.php">Home</a></li>
                                <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-item-child nav-item-hover" href="impressao-tabela.php">Table printing</a></li>
                                <li class="nav-item dropdown">
                                    <a class="nav-item-child nav-item-hover dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="navbarDropdown" role="button" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
                                      Graphics printing
                                    </a>
                                    <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdown" style="background-color: #20283f;">
                                        <a class="nav-item-child nav-item-hover dropdown-item" href="impressao-grafico-qualite.php">Graphic Qualite</a>
                                        <a class="nav-item-child nav-item-hover dropdown-item" href="impressao-grafico-vie.php">Graphic PRF VIE Série </a>
                                        <a class="nav-item-child nav-item-hover dropdown-item" href="impressao-grafico-projets.php">Graphic PRF Projets</a>
                                        <a class="nav-item-child nav-item-hover dropdown-item" href="impressao-grafico-gptw.php">Graphic GPTW</a>
                                    </div>
                                </li>
                                <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-item-child nav-item-hover" href="login.php">Logoff</a></li>
                            </ul>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </nav>
        </header>
        <!--Baner -->
        <div class="parallax-window" data-parallax="scroll" data-image-src="img/header-metade.jpg" style="height: 300px;">
            <div class="parallax-content container">
                <h1 class="carousel-title" style="font-size: 50px;">QUALITÉ</h1>
                <p>OBEYA DOPM 2018</p>
            </div>
        </div>

<div id="nota-print">      
        <!-- Main -->
        <div class="content-lg container">
          <div class="row margin-b-20">
              <div class="col-sm-6">
                  <h2>Prev x Real Month</h2>
              </div>
          </div>
          <div class="row">
            <div class="col-sm-12 sm-margin-b-50" >
              <div class="col-sm-6 sm-margin-b-2">
  <div class="">
    <div class="" data-height="height"> 
      <div class="service-info"> 
            <div id='container-tt-1' style='min-width: 210px; height: 300px; margin: 0 auto'></div>

              <script type='text/javascript'>
                Highcharts.chart('container-tt-1', {
                  chart: {
                    type: 'column'
                  },
                  title: {
                    text: 'QFS 3MR'
                  },
                  xAxis: {
                    categories: [
                      'Jan',
                      'Feb',
                      'Mar',
                      'Apr',
                      'May',
                      'Jun',
                      'Jul',
                      'Aug',
                      'Sep',
                      'Oct',
                      'Nov',
                      'Dec'
                    ],
                    crosshair: true
                  },
                  yAxis: {
                    min: 0,
                    title: {                             
                    }
                  },
                  tooltip: {

                    shared: true,
                    useHTML: true
                  },
                  plotOptions: {
                    column: {
                      pointPadding: 0.2,
                      borderWidth: 0
                    }
                  },
                  series: [{
                    name: 'Previsto',
                    data: [2, 2, 3, 2, 2, 9, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2]

                  }, {
                    name: 'Realizado',
                    data: [2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3]

                  }]
                  });
              </script>                           
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="col-sm-6 sm-margin-b-2">
  <div class="">
    <div class="" data-height="height"> 
      <div class="service-info">

              <div id='container-tt-10' style='min-width: 210px; height: 300px; margin: 0 auto'></div>

            <script type='text/javascript'>
              Highcharts.chart('container-tt-10', {
                chart: {
                  type: 'column'
                },
                title: {
                  text: 'CORE IQX BRUITS PIAR'
                },
                xAxis: {
                  categories: [
                    'Jan',
                    'Feb',
                    'Mar',
                    'Apr',
                    'May',
                    'Jun',
                    'Jul',
                    'Aug',
                    'Sep',
                    'Oct',
                    'Nov',
                    'Dec'
                  ],
                  crosshair: true
                },
                yAxis: {
                  min: 0,
                  title: {                             
                  }
                },
                tooltip: {

                  shared: true,
                  useHTML: true
                },
                plotOptions: {
                  column: {
                    pointPadding: 0.2,
                    borderWidth: 0
                  }
                },
                series: [{
                  name: 'Previsto',
                  data: [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]

                }, {
                  name: 'Realizado',
                  data: [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]

                }]
                });
            </script>
            </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="col-sm-6 sm-margin-b-2">
  <div class="">
    <div class="" data-height="height"> 
      <div class="service-info">

          <div id='container-tt-11' style='min-width: 210px; height: 300px; margin: 0 auto'></div>

            <script type='text/javascript'>
              Highcharts.chart('container-tt-11', {
                chart: {
                  type: 'column'
                },
                title: {
                  text: 'CORE IQX BRUITS PIBR'
                },
                xAxis: {
                  categories: [
                    'Jan',
                    'Feb',
                    'Mar',
                    'Apr',
                    'May',
                    'Jun',
                    'Jul',
                    'Aug',
                    'Sep',
                    'Oct',
                    'Nov',
                    'Dec'
                  ],
                  crosshair: true
                },
                yAxis: {
                  min: 0,
                  title: {                             
                  }
                },
                tooltip: {

                  shared: true,
                  useHTML: true
                },
                plotOptions: {
                  column: {
                    pointPadding: 0.2,
                    borderWidth: 0
                  }
                },
                series: [{
                  name: 'Previsto',
                  data: [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]

                }, {
                  name: 'Realizado',
                  data: [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]

                }]
                });
            </script>      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="col-sm-6 sm-margin-b-2">
  <div class="">
    <div class="" data-height="height"> 
      <div class="service-info">

          <div id='container-tt-12' style='min-width: 210px; height: 300px; margin: 0 auto'></div>

            <script type='text/javascript'>
              Highcharts.chart('container-tt-12', {
                chart: {
                  type: 'column'
                },
                title: {
                  text: 'ILPC'
                },
                xAxis: {
                  categories: [
                    'Jan',
                    'Feb',
                    'Mar',
                    'Apr',
                    'May',
                    'Jun',
                    'Jul',
                    'Aug',
                    'Sep',
                    'Oct',
                    'Nov',
                    'Dec'
                  ],
                  crosshair: true
                },
                yAxis: {
                  min: 0,
                  title: {                             
                  }
                },
                tooltip: {

                  shared: true,
                  useHTML: true
                },
                plotOptions: {
                  column: {
                    pointPadding: 0.2,
                    borderWidth: 0
                  }
                },
                series: [{
                  name: 'Previsto',
                  data: [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]

                }, {
                  name: 'Realizado',
                  data: [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]

                }]
                });
            </script>      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="col-sm-6 sm-margin-b-2">
  <div class="">
    <div class="" data-height="height"> 
      <div class="service-info">

          <div id='container-tt-13' style='min-width: 210px; height: 300px; margin: 0 auto'></div>

            <script type='text/javascript'>
              Highcharts.chart('container-tt-13', {
                chart: {
                  type: 'column'
                },
                title: {
                  text: 'TDD 3MR part fournisseurs'
                },
                xAxis: {
                  categories: [
                    'Jan',
                    'Feb',
                    'Mar',
                    'Apr',
                    'May',
                    'Jun',
                    'Jul',
                    'Aug',
                    'Sep',
                    'Oct',
                    'Nov',
                    'Dec'
                  ],
                  crosshair: true
                },
                yAxis: {
                  min: 0,
                  title: {                             
                  }
                },
                tooltip: {

                  shared: true,
                  useHTML: true
                },
                plotOptions: {
                  column: {
                    pointPadding: 0.2,
                    borderWidth: 0
                  }
                },
                series: [{
                  name: 'Previsto',
                  data: [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]

                }, {
                  name: 'Realizado',
                  data: [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]

                }]
                });
            </script>      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
</div>
        <a id="nota" class="btn btn-info btn-lg" onclick="printPageArea('nota-print');" title="Imprimir">
            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-print"></span> Imprimir 
        </a>

        <!-- Footer -->
        <footer class="footer" style="background-color: black;">
            <div class="content container">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-xs-8">
                        <p class="margin-b-0"><a class="color-base fweight-700">PSA GROUPE</a> Developer: <a class="color-base fweight-700" href="mailto:mariana.costa@ext.mpsa.com">Mariana Costa - U516709</a></p>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </footer>

        <!-- Back To Top -->
        <a href="javascript:void(0);" class="js-back-to-top back-to-top">Top</a>

        <!-- JAVASCRIPTS(Load javascripts at bottom, this will reduce page load time) -->
        <!-- CORE PLUGINS -->
        <script src="vendor/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
        <script src="vendor/jquery-migrate.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
        <script src="vendor/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

        <!-- PAGE LEVEL PLUGINS -->
        <script src="vendor/jquery.easing.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
        <script src="vendor/jquery.back-to-top.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
        <script src="vendor/jquery.smooth-scroll.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
        <script src="vendor/jquery.wow.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
        <script src="vendor/jquery.parallax.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
        <script src="vendor/swiper/js/swiper.jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

        <!-- PAGE LEVEL SCRIPTS -->
        <script src="js/layout.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
        <script src="js/components/swiper.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
        <script src="js/components/wow.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

    </body>
    <!-- END BODY -->
</html>
```

EDIT 2:

O QUE APARECE NO  DA  MINHA PÁGINA DO DESENVOLVEDOR:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Será que tem algum CSS influenciando nisto?

Comment: Coloca o seu código HTML e CSS ai também que vai facilitar pra te responder. Vc já está usando algum CSS para @media print ou @page ? Se vc está usando @media em alguma parte do seu CSS tente colocar `@media only screen` use o ONLY ou se já tem o ONLY retire o ONLY para testar como fica

Comment: Coloquei o código do print e da página. É muito provável que tenha algum css influenciando porque eu estou usando bootstrap para template e highcharts para o gráfico.

Comment: Parece que o Bootstrap tem algumas regras de `@media print` no CSS deles. Confere se lá tem algum estilo que na hora da impressão muda o Grid e coloca um campo embaixo do outro.

Comment: Tenta colocar essa classe na div onde o php vai vir dentro `.d-print-inline-flex` Se não de certo tenta pegar o código direto pelo browser, depois de renderizado na tela do navegador. Aperta Ctrl+U e copia o que está lá e edita a pergunta.

Comment: Procurando no bootstrap.min.css achei um .visible-print-inline que vou colocar o código na pergunta. Será que é isso que tá influenciando?

Comment: Mariana primeiro nessa div tenta mudar de col-sm-12 para col-sm-6 e faça o teste para ver como fica na tela e na hora da impressão `<div class="col-sm-6 sm-margin-b-50">`. Se a dica anterior não der certo tente incluir esse CSS no final do seu .css `@media print { .col-sm-12 { float: left !important; max-width: 50% !important; } }`

Comment: Então, testei as duas sugestões: Na primeira o gráfico ficou menorzinho mas a página de impressão continuou mostrando um gráfico abaixo do outro. Na segunda, a página de impressão continuou mostrando um gráfico abaixo do outro também.

Comment: Copia seu código direto da janela do browser. Abra a página no navegador. Aperta Ctrl+U copia o código que está lá e posta aqui editando a pergunta.

Comment: Prontinho, editei.

Comment: Parece que por algum motivo nenhum estilo do Bootstrap é aplicado no modo de impressão, então todos os elementos assumem o padrão `initial` deve ser por isso que fica um embaixo do outro. Mas com essa regra eu consegui ficar lado a lado `@media print { .col-sm-6 { width: 50%; float: left; } }`. Vc pode testa emulando a impressão direto no Chrome, Nessa resposta encima como fazer a emulação de impressão diretó na página https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/269790/imprimir-p%C3%A1gina-com-background/269803#269803

Comment: Tentei colocar no <style> da própria página que vai ser impressa, mas não tá resolvendo. Eu não to entendendo porque nada funciona.

Comment: Editei a pergunta com uma imagem do que aparece no meu style na página do desenvolvedor.

Comment: Não sei se isso é por alguma particularidade do Script do HighCharts, ou por especificidade do CSS que está sobrescrevendo classes... A última dica que posso te dar e começar um documento novo do Zero, ir colocando as coisas na mão e ver em qual momento ele começa a bugar. Cria uma página em branco só com o Bootstrap 3, depois cria o grid de duas colunas com algum conteúdo dentro e coloca o CSS `@media print { .col-sm-6 { width: 50%; float: left; } ` , agora vc já pode testar o preview da impressão para ver como fica. Se estiver ok inclui o HihgChart na coluna e testa novamente pra ver...

Comment: Então, consegui fazer os gráficos imprimirem um do lado do outro. Eu só estava colocando na página errada. Coloquei o css que me mandou na variável style do js que faz a impressão. Responde a pergunta pra eu dar como certa, tudo bem? Obrigada.