# CSS desconfigura ao imprimir

Tags: css, css3, twitter-bootstrap

Minha página está assim:

```
<div class="container">
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-12" style="border-style:solid;">
        <div style="text-align:center;" class="col-sm-12 col-md-12">
            <img style="text-align:center;" src="../uploads/logo.jpg" />
            <h4 style="text-align:center;">GUIA DE AGENDAMENTO</h4>
        </div>
        <div style="text-align:center;" class="col-sm-8 col-md-8">
            <p style="text-align:center;">
                Data de Atendimento<br/>{{date('d/m/Y', strtotime($marcacao->data))}}<br/><br/>
                Profissional<br/>{{$marcacao->agenda->vinculo->profissional->nome}}
            </p>
        </div>
        <div style="text-align:center;" class="col-sm-4 col-md-4">
            <p style="text-align:center;">
                Horário<br/>{{$marcacao->agenda->horario}}<br/><br/>
                Especialidades<br/>{{$marcacao->agenda->vinculo->funcao}}
            </p>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-12" style="border-style:solid;">
        <div style="text-align:center;" class="col-sm-12 col-md-12">
            <h4 style="text-align:center;">Paciente: {{$marcacao->cidadao->nome}}</h4>
        <div style="text-align:center;" class="col-sm-4 col-md-4">
            <p style="text-align:center;">
                CADSUS<br/>{{$marcacao->cidadao->cns}}
            </p>
        </div>
        <div style="text-align:center;" class="col-sm-4 col-md-4">
            <p style="text-align:center;">
                Telefone<br/>{{$marcacao->cidadao->telefone}}
            </p>
        </div>
        <div style="text-align:center;" class="col-sm-4 col-md-4">
            <p style="text-align:center;">
                Data de Nasc:<br/>{{date('d/m/Y', strtotime($marcacao->cidadao->dataNascimento))}}
            </p>
        </div>
    </div>        
</div>
```

Tem apenas os alinhamentos e as larguras das colunas. Quando vejo na tela, fica ok, se eu mandar direto pra impressora, ele ignora a largura das colunas. `col-md-8` e `col-md-4`, fica como se fosse `col-md-12`.

O que fazer?

Comment: uma dica, troque o `style="text-align:center"` pela classe do bootstrap `text-center`, fica mais limpo o código, aparentemente também falta fechar a div "container"

Comment: a div está fechada no codigo original. fiz as alteracoes e nao resolveu

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sobre o seu problema não existe nada na documentação oficial, mas ao que parece as colunas `col-*` ficam todas com 100% de largura, uma forma de corrigir isso seria criando um CSS exclusivo na `at-rule @print` para tratar isso.

Veja esse modelo base:

```
@media print {
  .col-print-1 {width:8%;  float:left;}
  .col-print-2 {width:16%; float:left;}
  .col-print-3 {width:25%; float:left;}
  .col-print-4 {width:33%; float:left;}
  .col-print-5 {width:42%; float:left;}
  .col-print-6 {width:50%; float:left;}
  .col-print-7 {width:58%; float:left;}
  .col-print-8 {width:66%; float:left;}
  .col-print-9 {width:75%; float:left;}
  .col-print-10{width:83%; float:left;}
  .col-print-11{width:92%; float:left;}
  .col-print-12{width:100%; float:left;}
}
```

Exemplo de uso:

```
<div class="col-md-6 col-print-6 clearfix">coluna com 50% de largura</div>
```

Imagem usando o exemplo acima:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

---

**Dicas**

Na documentação do Bootstrap não existem muitas referencias sobre ajustes para impressão. Eles relatam [um bug que pode aparecer no Safari com o tamanho das fontes](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.1/getting-started/browsers-devices/#printing)

E oferecem algumas classes para poder mudar o display do elemento na hora da impressão https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.1/utilities/display/#display-in-print

```
d-print-none
.d-print-inline
.d-print-inline-block
.d-print-block
.d-print-table
.d-print-table-row
.d-print-table-cell
.d-print-flex
.d-print-inline-flex
```

Usando as classes acima vc pode por exemplo mostrar ou esconder algum elemento apenas na impressão.

**Ex:** `<div class="d-none d-print-block">Print Only (Hide on screen only)</div>`

**Simular impressão no browser:** Nessa resposta tem umas dicas de como vc pode *simular o layout de impressão* direto no browser pelo DevTools do Chrome [Imprimir página com Background](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/269790/imprimir-p%C3%A1gina-com-background/269803#269803)