# Aplicar marca d'água sem afetar o texto

Tags: html, css

Coloquei uma imagem dentro de uma table representando a marca d'água, porém ao adicionar opacity na table todo o conteúdo é afetado.

Segue CSS:

```
table{
  background:url("../../../assets/img/empresa/business_logo.png") no-repeat; 
  background-size: 100% 100%;
  filter:alpha(opacity=50);
  filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(opacity=0.5);
  opacity:.50;
}
```

A table não tem nada de diferente, é uma table normal.

Alguma dica de como resolver esse problema? Não tenho como colocar essa imagem no `body` porque em uma folha vai ficar 3 carnês, então em cada carnê tem que ter sua marca.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: poe dinamicamente, por cima, aplicando a opacidade direto na imagem, calcula a altura e largura da tabela, e faz um js que centraliza no carne e aplica a opacidade.

Comment: Editei a resposta com um modelo que imprime a imagem no fundo da tabela. Basta copiar no seu projeto e testar.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Opção com `Background` transparente e que ao mesmo tempo aparece na hora de imprimir.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

De um <kbd>Ctrl+P</kbd> que vc vai ver que mesmo no "Modo de Impressão" do Browser a imagem vai ficar no fundo da Tabela.

```css
html, body {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
.container {
    position: relative;
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
}
.container table{
    background-image:linear-gradient( rgba(255,255,255,.7) 0%,rgba(255,255,255,.7) 100%), url("http://placecage.com/200/200"); 
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: 100% 100%;
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
} 
.container img {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    z-index: -1;
    opacity: 0.3;
    display: none;
}
@media print {
    .container table{
        background-image: none;
    }
    .container img {
        display: block;
    }
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
    <table border="1">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Item 1</th>
                <th>Item 2</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td>Texto 1</td>
                <td>Texto2</td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
    <img src="http://placecage.com/200/200" alt="">
</div>
```

---

Outras opções de `background` com opacidade, porém elas não estão otimizadas para impressão são apenas exemplos.

Jovem vou te dar uma solução sem precisar usar *opacity*, mas usando dois Background na tabela. Um coma a imagem, e por cima da imagem um *overlay* branco com cor RGBA e opacidade de 80% (vc pode colocar o valor que quiser no `linear-gradient`).

*Do jeito que vc fez, vc está colocando opacidade na tabela inteira, e não só no background.*

Veja no Snippet que vc vai entender a minha solução.

```css
table{
  background-image:linear-gradient( rgba(255,255,255,.8) 0%,rgba(255,255,255,.8) 100%), url("http://placecage.com/200/200"); 
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: 100% 100%;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
}
```

```html
<table border="1">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Item 1</th>
            <th>Item 2</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>Texto 1</td>
            <td>Texto2</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

---

Outra opção de imagem transparente no fundo da tabela sem afetar o conteúdo com um pseudo elemento `::after`

```css
table{
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  position: relative;
}
table::before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  opacity: .3; /* controla a opacidade da imagem */ 
  z-index: -1;
  background-image: url(http://placecage.com/250/250);
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: 100%
}
```

```html
<table border="1">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Item 1</th>
            <th>Item 2</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>Texto 1</td>
            <td>Texto2</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Muito obrigado.

Comment: Hugo, deu certo com a primeira opção, mas a imagem na aprece na impressão. Já coloquei ela dentro do @media print e nada. Alguma dica?

Comment: Sim, veja essa minha outra resposta. https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/269790/imprimir-p%C3%A1gina-com-background/269803#269803 por defaulta as impressoras não reconhecem imagens ou cores usadas como BackGround. Lá explica como resolver o problema. Mas se vc preferir posso fazer uma adaptação no meu código para deixa a imagem aparecer na impressão.

Comment: Já que ofereceu, adapta seu código. O do seu exemplo reslve, mas ele coloca uma imagem no centro da page e não no centro das tables, ou eu entendi errado.

Answer (score 1):

Envolver o conteúdo da tabela com uma div, então, aplicar o background e opacity na div, daria certo?

**HTML**

```
<table>
    <div id="marca">
        ...
    </div>
</table>
```

**CSS**

```
div#marca{
    background: url("../../../assets/img/empresa/business_logo.png");
    opacity: 0.5;
}

table {
    /* regras para a tabela */
}
```