# Imprimir pagina HTML mantendo o CSS da pagina

Tags: javascript, c#, webforms

Boa tarde pessoal, tenho um relatório que é gerado em um pagina `aspx` com `bootstrap` e `CSS`. O conteúdo do relatório fica dentro de uma `div <div id="pdf2htmldiv">...</div>` onde chamo via javascript para impressão. Mas a pagina é apresentada para impressão sem o `style` da pagina. Tem alguma forma de imprimir esse relatório conforme é apresentado com o `style CSS`?

Código javascript:

```
<script>
        function printDiv(divName) {
            var printContents = document.getElementById(divName).innerHTML;
            var originalContents = document.body.innerHTML;

            document.body.innerHTML = printContents;

            window.print();

            document.body.innerHTML = originalContents;
        }
    </script>
```

Chamada do botão:

```
<input type="button" onclick="printDiv('pdf2htmldiv')" value="Imprimir" />
```

Conteúdo da pagina:

```
<div id="pdf2htmldiv">
\\conteúdo do relatório
</div>
```

Relatório:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Relatório na impressão:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

O stylo da tabela `zebrada` não aparece nem as bordas do relatório. Consigo imprimir conforme a primeira imagem?

Comment: Vc quer fazer isso sem ir nas opções do navegador para imprimir gráficos de segundo plano?

Comment: Olha, pode ser um caso de opções de impressão como o comentário do @dvd indica, ou pode ser que o css que está usando não possa ser impresso. Poste o código css e ficará mais fácil

Comment: @dvd mesmo com as opções `imprimir gráficos de segundo plano` o stylo da tabela zebrada não aparece.

Comment: @DiegoSantos o css é o padrão do bootstrap para tabelas `class="table table-striped"`

Comment: Então provavelmente é o caso que o @dvd comentou. Já tentou isso?

Comment: @DiegoSantos Sim, já marquei `imprimir gráficos de segundo plano` nas opções de impressão.

Comment: Cara, então nesse caso acredito que dentro do @media print, deve colocar as cores como o bootstrap põe. Não dá pra reaproveitar, pq eles devem estar usando algo que não seja compatível. Acha que consegue?

Comment: @DiegoSantos Vou fazer novos testes com o @media print e setar o css da tabela `class="table table-striped"`

Comment: Acho que talvez não role assim. Talvez tenha que fazer na mão usando :nth-child(2n+1) ou algo do gênero. Manja?

Comment: @DiegoSantos Não manjo! Você poderia postar algum exemplo pratico?

Comment: Coloquei um exemplo. QQr coisa fala

Answer (score 2):

**Vou dar uma resposta que pode te ajudar sem vc ter que depender do usuário escolher imprimir os "Gráficos de Segundo Plano"**

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Como já discutido nessas duas perguntas a impressora por *Default* não imprimi nada que for `background` no CSS, nem imagens, nem cores, nem nada.

[Imprimir página com Background](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/269790/imprimir-p%C3%A1gina-com-background/269803#269803)

[Aplicar marca d'água sem afetar o texto](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/274605/aplicar-marca-d%C3%A1gua-sem-afetar-o-texto/274612#274612)

Porém existem técnicas que podem resolver esse problema. Como vou mostrar abaixo.

O primeiro passo é criar o seu CSS exclusivo que só vai usando o @print

Veja o exemplo abaixo funcionando, a cor vai ficar vermelha na impressão. A técnica é aplicar um `box-shadow` para dentro da célula, assim vc pode colocar a cor que quiser e vai aparecer na impressão sem problemas.

**Pode testar por aqui mesmo dando o <kbd>Ctrl+P</kbd> que vai funcionar!**

```css
html, body {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

table thead tr th {
    background: greenyellow; /* cor antes da impressão */
}

@media print{
  table thead tr th{
    box-shadow: 0 0 0 1000px red inset;  /* cor para impressão */
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
    <table border="1">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Item 1</th>
                <th>Item 2</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td>Texto 1</td>
                <td>Texto2</td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>
```

Resultado da impressão com o código acima, repare no box vermelho!

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Se vc quiser simular como a sua impressão vai ficar direto nã página sem precisar ficar apertando <kbd>Ctrl+P</kbd> toda hora basta habilitar o "Print Preview" direto pelo Dev Tools do Chrome dessa forma, aperte <kbd>F12</kbd>:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Vou fazer novos testes.

Comment: Evandro use o @print para sobrescrever os estilos que vc quer que só apareçam na impressão. Depois em dodos os lugares que tiver background-color vc coloca o box-shadow com inset conforme no exemplo da minha resposta que vc não terá problemas com cor de bg na impressão.

Answer (score 1):

Veja o exemplo como pediu.
Obs.: Caso não funcione aqui no stack, pegue o código e ponha num html local. Vai funcionar...

```css
@media print{
  table tbody tr:nth-child(2n+1){
    background: #CCC;
  }
}
```

```html
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Id</th>
      <th>Nome</th>
      <th>E-mail</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>Fulano 1</td>
      <td>fulano1@teste.com.br</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>2</td>
      <td>Fulano 2</td>
      <td>fulano2@teste.com.br</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>3</td>
      <td>Fulano 3</td>
      <td>fulan31@teste.com.br</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>4</td>
      <td>Fulano 4</td>
      <td>fulano4@teste.com.br</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>5</td>
      <td>Fulano 5</td>
      <td>fulano5@teste.com.br</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Diego por padrão as impressoras não imprimem "Gráficos de Segundo Plano" inclusive imagens e cores. Na verdade nada que é background no CSS vai para a impressão. Muito provavelmente seu código não funciona a não ser que vc (Manualmente) tenha escolhido essa opção na hora de imprimir, o que o usuário normal não faria! Teste seu código com a opção desmarcada e vc vai ver isso!

Comment: Então, é sobre isso os comentários na pergunta dele inclusive. Ele tentou marcar a opção de imprimir gráficos e não estava indo mesmo assim. testei meu código e com a opção marcada ele funciona. Agora é óbvio, com o gráfico desativado não funcionará. Porém isso já foi discutido acima @hugocsl

Comment: @DiegoSantos Vou fazer novos testes.