# background image nao sai na impressão (utilizando o window.print)

Tags: javascript, html, css, front-end, impressão

Preciso imprimir uma pagina que tem uma imagem de fundo como background, uma logo em marca dagua.

Porém utilizando o window.print() o background não aparece na imrpessão (a não ser que o usuario marque "background graphics" na pagina de impressão no chrome.

Pesquisei e achei uma linha de codigo em css que força o chrome a imprimir a color do background, mas não achei o codigo que força a imprimir a "image".

Codigo da pagina:

```
   <html lang="pt-BR">
            <link href="css/impressao.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
            <script type="text/javascript" src="js/main.js"></script>
        </head>
        <body>
            <script type="text/javascript">
                window.print();
                window.location.href = '../home.php';

            </script>
        </body>
    </html>
```

CSS:

```
body{
    background-image: url(../img/MARCA.png);
    background-size: 100% 100%;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: center;
}
```

Ps. sintetizei o código apenas para a parte que é relevante para a questão, para facilitar o entendimento.

Alguém pode ajudar?

Comment: O seu problema é que a impressora por default não reconhece nada que esteja como Background. Aqui tem uma resposta que vai te ajudar! https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/274605/aplicar-marca-d%C3%A1gua-sem-afetar-o-texto?noredirect=1 se não te servir coloca seu código na pergunta que fica mais fácil!

Comment: Não é o caso. A imagem foi tratada para parecer marca dagua, e não adquiriu essa caracteristica atraves do codigo.

Comment: Seu body e seu HTML tem setado altura e largura? Tipo: `html, body { width: 100%; height: 100%; }`

Comment: Sim estão. A visualização da pagina está ok. O unico problema é que na hora de imprimir essa imagem setada como background não aparece na impressão. (pelo que entendi isso é padrão do chrome, a não ser que o usuario clique na tal caixa ''graficos de segundo plano'' na tela de impressão. O que eu preciso é que essa caixa ja venha marcada quando o codigo solicitar a impressão da pagina

Comment: Cara eu acho que vc não vai conseguir habilitar isso por uma questão de segurança do Browser. Tirando isso vc pode consultar essa outra resposta que deve te atender https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/269790/imprimir-p%C3%A1gina-com-background/269803#269803

Comment: qual a tag que você usou pra "obrigar" a impressão de ```background-color```?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No Chrome e no Safari é possível adicionar a regra CSS:

```
-webkit-print-color-adjust: exact;
```

Isso vai forçar o navegador a imprimir as cores e imagens de fundo.

Fonte: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/-webkit-print-color-adjust

Comment: Vacilo meu. Tinha encontrado essa linha de código, porem achei que ela era limitada ao atributo ''background-color". Cheguei a colocar mas modifiquei para "-webkit-print- IMAGE -adjust: exact;", obviamente não deu certo. Obrigado mesmo.