# Formulário para impressão de carteirinha escolar

Tags: javascript, html

Estou tentando desenvolver um HTML simples para criação de carteirinha escolar e R.A., no qual eu entre no arquivo, digite as informações do aluno e consiga imprimir, tanto pela própria página quanto por um botão.

Por enquanto eu estou tentando pela página: coloquei uma background do layout da carteirinha R.A. de fundo, e ajustei as caixas de texto corretamente sobre os campos que eu quero que seja escrito, até ai tudo ok.

Mas quando eu vou mudar de caixa de texto para outra, as caixas parecem que bugam, saem do local dimensionado, quando escreve em uma parece que está escrevendo na outra do lado, e quando aperto para imprimir no <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>P</kbd> ela apenas aparece os campos, sem a background.

Alguém poderia me ajudar referente a esse caso? Só tenho conhecimento referente a HTML e PHP, mas não estou conseguindo entender as funções necessárias para esse problema.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

E quando vou imprimir:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Se não me engano, para imprimir planos de fundo no chorme tem que marcar a opção "Gráficos de segundo plano".

Comment: Aqui tb deve te ajudar https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/200776/bootstrap-como-imprimir-cores-de-fundo-da-tabela/292813#292813